# Sending back collection of view models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have not used asp.net mvc 3 for a while (got side tracked). I can't remember is it good practice to send back a collection of view models?

Right now how I have my code is I have a view model that contains other view models. This way I only ever send back one view model.

The view models in this one view model could be a collection though. However I have a case where I need to send multiple view models back but that's all I need to send. I don't have any other properties or other view models getting sent back.

It seems kinda pointless to wrap it around another view model just to make it only return one view model.

So is it good practice or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with that approach.  Pass back whatever is necessary to render the View.  You can certainly refactor later if you require additional data to be passed to your View.

Answer (score 0):

I only pass one `ViewModel` to a `View`. BUT, that single `ViewModel` might have some properties which are *OTHER* `ViewModels`.

here's a sample view model for my homepage....

```
namespace RavenOverflow.Web.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class IndexViewModel : _LayoutViewModel
    {
        public IndexViewModel(ICustomIdentity customIdentity) : base(customIdentity)
        {
        }

        public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public AuthenticationViewModel AuthenticationViewModel { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, short> RecentPopularTags { get; set; }
        public UserTagListViewModel UserFavoriteTagListViewModel { get; set; }
        public UserTagListViewModel UserIgnoredTagList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The 2nd, 4th and 5th properties all contain individual ViewModels.

I grabbed this from [some tutorial code I wrote up recently](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/tree/master/Code/RavenOverflow.Web).

Comment: Ya that is how I normally(expect I might break down Questions into a view model as well). However I am asking in this case as I don't have any other view models or any other properties going along with it. Seems pointless right now to wrap it in another view model for the sake of wrapping it in another view model.

Comment: If there's -nothing- else at all in the viewmodel .. then I don't use a viewmodel. In my example above, Questions property will be pasted to a Partial .. so that's a simple scenario. But once I have any View logic .. it generally means I need two or more properties .. and thus a ViewModel is born. I -never- do any logic in a View. Eg. Do I show this button or not? that is either defined in the ViewModel property OR via the controller. The view model only ever does if (property == true | false) .. show some Html .. and of course foreach's.....